# How to pop a view using popViewControllerAnimated by pressing on a button which is from a subview?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating a photo browser.

The user selects a cell from a `UITableView`, and pushes them to a photo browser view using `UINavigationController`.

In my "PhotoBrowser.m", I have:

```
    //Caption UIView
    CGRect capFrame = CGRectMake(1024-400, 0, 400, 768);
    overlayWindow = [[UICaptionOverlay alloc] initWithFrame:capFrame];
    overlayWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self addSubview:overlayWindow];
```

I call a subview and overlay the contents on my image. i.e. Putting captions on a series of photos.

In my subview "UICaptionOverlay.m", I have a button:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 300, 200, 50)];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[button setTitle:@"Return to Table View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedClose) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:button];
[button release];
```

This displays a `UIView` with some labels and a button on top of my photos.

When the button is pressed, how do I bring the user back to the `UITableView`, and select another cell?

I can call:

```
[photoBrowser performSelector:@selector(popViewControllerToTable) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

from "PhotoBrowser.m", so I know at least the view can be popped.

*popViewControllerToTable has [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];*

Thanks to all in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is keeping a reference to your parent viewController in the `UICaptionOverlay` instance.

Then call this in the `buttonPressedClose` selector:

`[self.myParentViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Thanks!

used  `[self.superview.buttonPressClose];` in UICaptionOverlay

to call up another `buttonPressClose` in PhotoBrowser.m,

which runs the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

It works fine now.

Thaks again!